# MFMailComposeViewController not dismiss

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, dismiss

I used `MFMailComposeViewController` for sending mail to others. When click a button the compose sheet is opening, and i can able to type To address,subject,message body. But after clicking send button the mail page is not closing.

code:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:@"My image"];


    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mobiletuts-logo.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);           


    [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Image"];
    NSString *emailBody = @"Hi, my image";
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];          

    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
 } 

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hope u add `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol in your .h file.

Comment: yes. I added. But it's not working

Comment: Den it looks strange, bcoz I dont find any other mistakes in the code. Did u check whether the delegate method was called?

Comment: I got answer. See the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry. Forget to add these lines. After this lines mail working

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
```

for dismiss

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```